# Gradle apply plugin vs plugins

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a simple plugin with  `greet` task doing some 'Hello World' print.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'standalone.plugin2.greeting'
version = '1.0'

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'standalone.plugin2.greeting'
            implementationClass = 'standalone.plugin2.StandalonePlugin2Plugin'    
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'standalone.plugin2.greeting'
            version = '1.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have runner application to just run the `greet task`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'standalone.plugin2.greeting:standalone-plugin2:1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'standalone.plugin2.greeting'
```

With `apply plugin` notation it works OK, but when I use plugins notation instead like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'standalone.plugin2.greeting' version '1.0'
}
```

it doesn't work.

The error message is:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'standalone.plugin2.greeting', version: '1.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'standalone.plugin2.greeting:standalone.plugin2.greeting.gradle.plugin:1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

What is the difference? According to documentation `apply plugin` is old and should not be used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before the introduction of the `plugins` block, plugin dependencies had to be resolved in the same way as regular project dependencies using a combination of `repositories` and `dependencies`. Since they need to be resolved before running the actual build script, they need to be defined in the special `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // define repositories for build script dependencies
    }
    dependencies {
        // define build script dependencies (a.k.a. plugins)
    }
}

repositories {
    // define repositories for regular project dependencies
}

dependencies {
    // define regular project dependencies
}
```

Once the dependencies were resolved, they could be applied using `apply plugin:`.

By default, the new `plugins` block just resolves the plugins from the [Gradle Plugin Repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/). This is a regular Maven repository, so it can be used using the old way, too:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, the plugin only exists in `mavenLocal`, so the `plugins` block cannot resolve it, as it only looks into the Gradle Central Plugin Repository. You may use the `pluginManagement` block to [resolve plugins from custom repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories).

As described in the article linked above, it is necessary to create a link between the plugin identifier (used inside the `plugins` block) and the Maven coordinates that provide the respective plugin. To create this link a marker artifact following a specific convention must be published. The [Gradle Plugin Development Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html) automatically publishes this marker artifact if used in combination with the [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Comment: A made a `pluginManagement` in the `settings.gradle`, and now my plugin is resolved, but task `greet` is not found. I guess I'll stick with `apply plugin` then.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to properly declare the `mavenLocal()` repository in order for a plugin to be resolved in the plugins section? I have the same issue and I couldn't solve it with `pluginManagement`.

Comment: @SashaShpota Could you create another question with the code you tried and the issues you encountered?

Comment: @LukasKörfer the problem is exactly the same as OP describes it (with `apply` it works, with `id "plugin-d"` it does not). You suggest to use `pluginManagement`, but it deson't work in my case. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @SashaShpota The problem is, that without any code of what you tried so far, I can only take a guess. If this would be your own question, I would recommend you to edit the question to include the code involving `pluginManagement` and the code how your plugin is published. But it is not your question, so you should **not** edit it, as it could confuse future readers. Now the only way to get a look at your code is a new question (linking to this one).

Comment: @SashaShpota To actually take a guess: Do you use the [`java-gradle-plugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#java_gradle_plugin) plugin for your plugin project? If not, you need to manually publish plugin marker artifacts to create a link between your plugin identifier (used inside the `plugins` block) and the actual artifact that should be resolved from the Maven repositories.

Comment: I do use `java-gradle-plugin`. I publish the plugin to maven local via `./gradlew install` and use the plugin in a different project. The problem is that it works with `apply`, but it doesn't work with the `plugins {...}` declaration.

Comment: @SashaShpota The `maven` plugin (that creates the `install` task) is deprecated and should not be used. Use the `maven-publish` plugin instead, as it will be configured by the `java-gradle-plugin` plugin. You may then call `gradle publishToMavenLocal` to publish your plugin and it should automatically publish the marker artifact. If you encounter any additional problems, please open a new question.